# How to get the key of ajax response array in order to build up header of datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatable

I have a `$.post` query, where I am retrieving json data from a ajax response. The issue is I want to load the data in a datatable and the header of the table need to be created dynamically.

My json data comes in a format:

```
[{"id":"11105","name":"Gummy Drop (iPhone, Free, ROW except CN, 72.3MB, w"},{"id":"11107","name":"Gummy Drop (iPad, Free, ROW except CN, 72.3MB, w\/ "},{"id":"4274","name":"Z-Redirect Non-Targeted Traffic Dragon City Mobile"},{"id":"6484","name":"Z-Redirect Non-Targeted Traffic Dragon City Mobile"}]
```

As you all can see, the two keys are `id` and `name`. I want to get the two keys and use as header column but I am unable to do so.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.prettyPrint() && prettyPrint();


    $('#load').click(function()
    {
        var v = $('#drp_v').val();
        var cnt = $('#drp_cnt').val();
        var ctg = $('#drp_ctg').val();
        alert("version :"+v+" category :"+ctg+" country :"+cnt);
        $.post("ajax.php",{'version':v,'category':ctg,'country':cnt,'func':'show_datatable'},
                        function(data)
                        {
                            var aColumns = [{ sTitle: "Week"}, { sTitle: "Winkelformule" }];
                            var oTable = $('#jsontable').dataTable({
                                "columns":aColumns,
                                "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                                    "oTableTools": {

                                        "aButtons": [


                                             {
                                                    "sExtends": "csv",
                                                    "sButtonText": "CSV",

                                             }
                                        ]
                                    }

                            });
                            oTable.fnClearTable();
                            alert(data);
                            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                            {
                                 oTable.fnAddData([
                                            data[i].id,
                                            data[i].name
                                                   ]);                                      
                            } // End For
                        },'json');
    });
});
```

As you can see this line:

`var aColumns = [{ sTitle: "Week"}, { sTitle: "Winkelformule" }];` is creating the `<thead>`.

Now my two issues are:

a) I want to use the keys over here so that the thead can be dynamic.

b) Secondly, you can see I am initialising the datatable upon the ajax call. That means every time the ajax is called, the datatable is initialised. I want to eliminate that. I want the datatable to be initialised once, but the `<thead>` will be created each time the ajax call will be fired. but I just only know to create `<thead>` during initialisation of the datatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Object.keys](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3.14) is probably what you are looking for.

```
response = $.post(YOUR_AJAX_PAAGE)
aColumns = [{ sTitle: "Week"}, { sTitle: "Winkelformule" }]; 
registerredKeys = [];
for(i = 0; i<response.length; i++){
      keycolumns = Object.keys(response[i]); //Get keys of each object
      for(j = 0; j < keycolumns.length; j++){
          if($.inArray({sTitle: keycolumns[j]},registerredKeys)<=0){
               aColumns.push({sTitle: keycolumns[j]}) //Checks if 
               registerredKeys.push( keycolumns[j]);
          }
      }
}
```

Then render `aColumns`. Solves problem a. For problem b you probably need to craft your json response so that you can get all keys before hand otherwise you'd end up initializing thead over and overagain because you don't know all the data. You could keep a running list to see if new columns have been registered. (make PreviousKeys public and run this after the above piece of code.

```
if(Object.toJson(registerredKeys) === PreviousKeys){
     //Ignore 
}else{
   PreviousKeys = Object.toJson(registerredKeys)
   //Render new thead
}
```

Comment: Whoops made typo length is a property not function. Edited it... should work on chrome

Comment: it seems the cColumns is not getting built up properly

Comment: updated the check. I had to use registerredKeys (a separate list containing your columns);